# UIButton inheritance doesnt show image

Tags: objective-c, inheritance, uibutton, uiimage

I am trying to make an inheritance of a UIButton. Which if clicked will play a sound , scales up. And when finishes playing sound scales back to the original state.
Everything is working except the image is not showing.
The title and background do scale up, and the sound is being played.
Anyone a hint?
**soundButton.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>

@interface soundButton : UIButton <AVAudioRecorderDelegate, AVAudioPlayerDelegate>{
    BOOL                isPlaying;
    AVAudioPlayer       *audioPlayer;
}
@property (nonatomic)BOOL       isPlaying;
@property (nonatomic, strong) AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame;
-(void)loadSound:(NSString*)audiofile;
-(void)touchUpInside;
@end
```

**soundButton.m**

```
#import "soundButton.h"
@implementation soundButton
@synthesize isPlaying;
@synthesize audioPlayer;
void audioRouteChangeListenerCallback (
                                   void *inUserData,
                                   AudioSessionPropertyID inPropertyID,
                                   UInt32 inPropertyValueSize,
                                   id *inPropertyValue);

-(BOOL)isPlaying{
return audioPlayer.isPlaying;
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {
    [self addTarget:self action:@selector(touchUpInside) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"kers.png"];
    [self setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}
return self;
}
-(void)loadSound:(NSString*)audiofile{
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                     pathForResource:audiofile
                                     ofType:nil]];

NSError *error;
audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
if (error)
{
    NSLog(@"Error in audioPlayer: %@",
          [error localizedDescription]);
} else {
    audioPlayer.delegate = self;
    [audioPlayer setVolume:1.0];
    [audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
    audioPlayer.currentTime = 0;
 }
 }

-(void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag{
   [audioPlayer setCurrentTime:0];
self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.5,1.5);
self.alpha = 1.0f;
[UIView beginAnimations:@"fish" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0,1.0);
self.alpha = 1.0f;
[UIView commitAnimations];

self.isPlaying = NO;
 }

-(void)touchUpInside{
//Check if something is playing If YES=>stop it
if (self.isPlaying) {
    [audioPlayer stop];
    [audioPlayer setCurrentTime:0];
} else {

    self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0,1.0);
    self.alpha = 1.0f;
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"fish" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.5,1.5);
    self.alpha = 1.0f;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}


// Create an asynchronous background queue
        NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
        [queue addOperationWithBlock:
         ^{
                 [audioPlayer play];
        }];
}
@end
```

implemented in ViewdidLoad in the viewController:

```
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:@"cherry.png"];
fishButton = [[soundButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(323, 312, 123, 123)];

[fishButton setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[fishButton loadSound:@"chime1.mp3"];
[fishButton setTitle:@"fish" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[fishButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
[fishButton setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:YES];

[self.view addSubview:fishButton];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace this

```
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:@"cherry.png"];
```

with this

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cherry.png"];
```

or if you really need to use `initWithContentsOfFile` use URL link like

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"cherry" ofType:@"png"];
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

Comment: Wow! Thanx!I just found out that adding:

Comment: + (id)buttonWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    return [[self alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
} also solved the problem... Any idea why?

Comment: No idea... you had problems with your previous implementation, presumably, you've fixed it without noticing and used another init call, which made you think that it is the init call that fixed the issue.